# Transform array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'd like to transform input array from:

```
array(1) {
  ["option"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "fdfsafsd"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "dasdasd"
...
  }
}
```

to

```
array(array('option' => "fdfsafsd"), array('option' => "dasdasd"),...)
```

The key "option" can be whatever...

What would be the best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: cant be same key in array here u write `option` twice

Comment: This is not possible, because in php array keys are unique.

Comment: Best practice - you can`t. You can`t assign value two times to the same index in array.

Comment: keys of array should be unique

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that since you would not be able to properly access `$array['option']` as the key would exist twice.

Comment: If option can be whatever, why not just access it with array['option']? Do you mean you want to remove that bit?

Comment: Sorry I'm am a moron.. I know that I can't do that... I don't know why I wrote it that way... what I meant was... array(array('option' => '...'), array('option' => '...'), ... )

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to leave your array as it is. If you want to "transform" it, you need to assign new keys for values found in the "options" key.

```
$new_array = $old_array['options'];
```

That would get what you specified in your question, however I don't see why you'd do that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you want to have an associative array with all the value on one key ???
That seems impossible because an associative array is one key => one Value.

so you probably want an array list, you can obtain it easely by:

$myArray = $originalArray['option']
which will be like that:
array("fdfsafsd", "dasdasd",...)